# How can I determine which part of the game is best/worst for a particular champion?

Tags: league-of-legends

Some champions are stronger in the laning phase while others snowball into a strong endgame. For example Kog'maw is weak early game, average mid game, and strong late game.

A list of champions categorized by when they are strong or weak in a game phase would be welcome. If such a list does not exist, is there a way to estimate this from a champion's skills and equipment build (without actually playing them)?

Comment: This may be difficult to accomplish as Riot aims to make champions balanced the entire game, so the information would be changing pretty frequently.  As an example, before this week's patch, Garen was strong early game avg mid, weak late, now in theory Riot adjusted him to be avg all game.

Comment: There are too many champions (each with potentially multiple build options) to properly answer this. Asking for a list does not make a good question.

Comment: I have edited your question (a bit heavily) to get the intent across without just asking for an ill-defined list, it might help get you a better answer. Please revert if you disagree with the changes.

Comment: Brian, your comment makes sense.  Yes, such a list would vary patch by patch.  However it would still be possible.  Raven, I disagree with your comment.  There are some champions which (given their current stats) are inherently stronger early game (Corki, Tristana, Graves) and some which are inherently stronger later (Kog'maw, Vladimir).  These are just a couple examples, but it's certainly the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a trivial task and it depends on the lane opponent as well as the role. The only definitive answer is experience.

As an example for an AD Carry you have to look at the base stats, calculate the potential damage and burst as well as the survivability for each level and compare it to other AD Carrys. However, this still gives wrong information since for example Caitlyn with relatively weak burst still has an extremely strong laning phase against many AD Carrys due to her huge range.

As a few rules of thumb:

- Champions with good area of effect Skills are stronger lategame than earlygame since they are more effective in teamfights when they can actually hit multiple targets (ex.: Anivia, Graves)
- Single target burst champions (Assassins) are weak early on, strong in the midgame and fall off lategame when their damage is no longer enough to instantly kill someone (ex.: LeBlanc, Kassadin)
- Champions with a strong long range skill (poking skill) are very useful lategame to soften up opponents prior to engagements but are usually weaker in the laning phase (ex.: Kog'Maw)
- Tanks have a weak early laning phase due to their low damage but become very strong lategame due to their influence on teamfights (ex.: Malphite)
- Champions with crowd control effects (Stuns, snares, blinds, knock ups, knock backs,...) are strong all game long (ex.: Alistar)
- Mobile champions are strong midgame where they can roam but their mobility often comes at the cost of sustained DPS, making them less effective in teamfights (ex.: Ezreal)
- Skill shot based champions are weak in the laning phase but stronger in lategame/teamfights where it's harder to dodge the skill shots

Note that all those rules depend on the actual champion, the opponents, the team composition, the player skill, etc.

As an example i wrote above that Ezreal is less effective in teamfights, which is true only if both teams protect (i.e. peel) for the AD carry, which is often not the case in <1200 ELO teams. If the teams don't peel, the good mobility of Ezreal will be more important than the sustained damage output, giving him an edge in teamfights compared to a stronger, less mobile AD carry.

Comment: This is a great answer.  +1.  I'd like to wait for more answers before accepting it though.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your champion. If your champion is carry, then its obviosly late part of game, if your support ganker/procaster, then its early-mid for sure. If support, you can be useful whole game. For tanks mid-late game.